# Asp.net MVC - Map Claim identity to custom user identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, claims-based-identity, acs

I'm trying to figure where is the best extension point in the ASP.NET MVC3 infrastructure to map custom user informations (loaded from local database) after received the Claim Authentication from Azure AccessControl Service 2.0

I tried to achieved this by overriding the Authenticate method of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsAuthenticationManager class :

```
public class ClaimsTransformationModule : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
{
    public override IClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, IClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        // Load User from database and map it to HttpContext
        // Code here

        return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
    }
}
```

However, it seems that this method is called more than once during the page loading request.
Loading custom user informations here could produce a performance issue.
I would like to load them only once per authenticated session.

Is there a better place to do that ?
Perhaps somewhere at a lower level where the IClaimsPrincipal is constructed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do an `isAuthenticated` check:

```
if (incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   // Load User from database and map it to HttpContext
   // Code here
}
```

This will only run once after the user is first authenticated.

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Put a debug mark inside that if statement, you will see its being run more than once.

Answer (score 1):

This is only running once when the user is logging in.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
            FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SecurityTokenValidated += WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenValidated;
        }

        void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SecurityTokenValidated(object sender, SecurityTokenValidatedEventArgs e)
        {
            IClaimsPrincipal principal = e.ClaimsPrincipal;
            IClaimsIdentity identity = (IClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

            try
            {
                //SQL connection / Claims injeciotn
                if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                   // identity.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "WebAdmins"));
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                //Error
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any user information which is not coming from the STS is satellite data about the user. So it would be best to represent this with Asp .Net ProfileProvider infrastructure.

**Update:**

Another thing which you can do is implemeting a simple Custom STS which will add your custom claims coming from your DB, into the incoming claims. Your Custom STS will trust ACS and will take SAML tokens, and it will be trusted by your web applition.

Another thing, which I haven't tried, would be attempting to tamper with the claims coming from STS. One thing which you can give a try is registering to the SecurityTokenValidated event of the WSFederationAuthenticationModule. In this event you can try to add your additional claims into ClaimsPrincipal of the event arg.

This event should be raised before the session token is created, so you sould be looking up db once per login.

cheers,

Comment: My question is about identity. ProfileProvider is for storing user data not identity. You probably talk about MembershipProvider. What i'm trying to figure is where i can plug my custom user (IIdentity, IPrincipal) in the Claim reception flow.

Comment: User identity is validated by a 3rd party Identity Provider which is trusted by ACS. Then ACS, as the Secure Token Server packages this identity into a token and sends it to your application. In this aspect the identity of the user should ideally only be coming from the trusted STS, ACS.

If you would like to add additional claims into user identity the proper way of doing this would be adding a custom STS, which has trust relationship with ACS (WS Federation Server), and then trusting from your RP app to this custom STS.